# Wordpress manually Attach Images to Post using SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have created a custom post type called products and need to associate multiple images with one product. The actual data already exists in a different non-wordpress database in a table called productimages that simply has a productid, imageurl, and image title. I need to convert this data into wordpress format so wordpress can display everything I need. This is something that will be done regularly using sql automatically deleting products and meta data related and re-adding from our main database which changes regularly.

From what I can tell, the best way to make this work is to manually use sql to insert the productimages as attachment posts just like wordpress does when you upload media to wordpress. Then to associate the image with a product I have to manually insert records into postmeta but the data in postmeta is serialized or something and I am unsure how I would insert the data in the correct serialize format using mysql. Is it even possible to do this with mysql?

Am I going about this wrong? Should I be doing something different? I was originally going to use custom fields till I realized a custom field can only have one value and I needed two values: imageurl and imagetitle for each image. So it seems programatically creating a post type of attachment for each image is the best way to go. yes?

I look forward to anyone's response to help in this matter.

Comment: You know that serialization exists; now you should realize that even though a custom field can only have one value, that value can be a serialized form of many values. It can be as simple as separating the imageurl and imagetitle by a comma, then separating the string at the comma in your template. You can also have infinite custom fields for each post, so you can have infinite imageurl and imagetitle entries.

Comment: yes I understand serialization would be a great solution.... I just need to figure out how to write a simple php script that uses serialzation. I'm unsure is serialization special to wordpress or can i use it outside of wordpress to serialize a multi dimensional array and then within wordpress unserialize it on a wordpress template page to display to the end user or is there some special serialize settings wordpress uses? Any such resources in regards to this?

Comment: You must learn to start referencing the PHP manual. Heck, just type "php [word]" into Google. "php serialize" would immediately lead you to the manual page and you'd see it's nothing special to WordPress (and you could write your own serialization method damn easily anyway, I already described how mentioning separating two values by a comma) [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), [implode](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [explode](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Thanks Dan. I did read the manual but I wasn't sure if there was some special serialize function exclusive to wordpress maybe. thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: WordPress does have a serialize function, [maybe_serialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize), which you can find by doing the Google search "wordpress serialize". It is implemented with PHP's serialize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert on serialization for wordpress but have you checked the wordpress php function [maybe_serialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize)

Comment: It looks like I have to write a custom php script that will serialize and unserialize the arrays.